# how to redirect with navigate in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a static navigationOptions and i made a headerRight to put a button to disconnect.
the problem is I don't know how to redirect !

here is my navigationOptions :

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Profile",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#4169E1"
    },
    headerTintColor: "white",
    headerRight: (
      <Button
      onPress={() => removeItem()}
      title="Disconnect"
      color="white"
      />
    )
  };
```

so it calls a function removeItem() to delete the item with AsyncStorage :

```
export async function removeItem() {
    console.log("navigate => ", this.props);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("login");
    console.log("item login removed");
    navigate("Home") //something like that
    return ;
}
```

how can i redirect to the page "Home" with navigate ?
thx for help !

Comment: Where is this removeItem fuction located ?

Comment: `this.props` will be available inside react component. You are inside a function which does not extend `Component`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-navigation, I suppose you use `createStackNavigator`, so you can use

```
export async function removeItem() {
    console.log("navigate => ", this.props);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("login");
    console.log("item login removed");

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') // redirect to home

    return ;
}
```

Or if you want to back to previous screen, you can use `pop`:

```
const popAction = StackActions.pop({
  n: 1, // number of screens to pop back by.
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(popAction);
```

Comment: Hello,
i've already tried this.props.navigation.navigte("Home") it doesnt work. I got undefined, how can i solve this ?

Comment: You are using react-navigation ?

Comment: Yes I am, but i'm new with react native

Comment: Ok, if you are using react-navigation, you had to have configured the `createStackNavigator`, are you do that ?, this is an example https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/going-back-v3